# How to check if a user came to site by clicking a specific link?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, tealium

We have a external website say www.my-mainsite1.com and it has web page which has a link("link to subsite1") to subsite say www.my-subsite1.com.

When a user is on www.my-subsite1.com, how to check the user came by clicking "link to subsite1" on www.my-mainsite.com

We have limitations on using query string to www.my-subsite1.com. So, any suggestions/tools to identify the link clicks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use a `query` param, you can use **[`document.referrer` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)** in your website:

> The `Document.referrer` property returns the URI of the page that linked to this page

It will show you the origin site of the request, otherwise it will be a blank string if the site was opened directly.

**Example of a site opened from a `link`:**

[image]

**Another one without `referrer`:**

[image]

Comment: Note: I clicked a link from an email, and document.referrer was empty. That may not work for links from emails.

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron yes right links opened from an email doesn't have a referrer because it's out of the browser scope.