# How to check if user came from a follow or nofollow link

Tags: javascript

Is there any solution to check if a user came from a follow or nofollow link ?

I search this but there is no such question asked before .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a user came to site by clicking a specific link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61141814/how-to-check-if-a-user-came-to-site-by-clicking-a-specific-link)

Comment: No at all.......

Comment: There is no difference between the HTTP headers. `rel="nofollow"` only informs search engine crawlers not to follow the link.

Comment: So what that mean ? we cannt return if the link was follow or nofollow ?

Comment: Exactly. The HTTP request to your server is identical, you can check that yourself. So you cannot determine the difference, unless you have some other information you're not telling us.

Comment: There is no difference between a link without `rel="nofollow"` and with `rel="nofollow"` to the server which receives the request.

Comment: Why do you care? As pointed out, this is just advice to search engines, why would it matter for ordinary users clicking on links? Are you trying to determine if a search engine is ignoring the `nofollow` attribute?